# In Doctrine 1.2, how do I access glue object properties in a many-to-many relationship?

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

I have an Article model and a Photo model, and I am currently using a query like this to join the two:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
       ->from('Article a')
       ->leftJoin('a.Photo p');
```

For binding them together, I have an `ArticlePhoto` model. In addition to `article_id` and `photo_id` fields, the model also has a `priority INT` field, with which I want to sort the Photos in the above query.

Any suggestions how I can achieve this, without having to join through a query like this:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
       ->from('Article a')
       ->leftJoin('a.ArticlePhoto ap')
       ->leftJoin('ap.Photo p')
       ->orderBy('ap.priority');
```

There is a lot of code expecting to find the first photo for the article in `$article['Photo'][0]`, so I want to avoid having to change this. Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with the joins? You can always rewrite your query to this:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
   ->from('Article a')
   ->leftJoin('a.ArticlePhoto ap, ap.Photo p')
   ->orderBy('ap.priority');
```

Which looks like a perfectly fine query without any magic. You need information from the ArticlePhoto table (for sorting), so doing an explicit join is the right thing to do.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry about the delayed response :) I did like you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
   ->from('Photo p')
   ->orderBy('priority');
```

The above will do the trick. Please know that there is not need to join tables which have relations(assuming that in your example the tables are having 1:m relation in the schema). You can acees the article object as stated bellow

```
$photoObjectCollection=$q->execute();
foreach($photoObjectCollection as $photoObject){
    $photoObject->Article->requiredField;
}
```

Comment: `priority` is a field in `ArticlePhoto` not in `Photo`. I don't think your query do the trick.

Comment: And if I simply use $photoObject->Article->requiredField - it seems to use another DB query every time I access the Article field. I would rather request all needed data with the same query.